# Compiling HTML5 app using Phonegap issue

Tags: android, html, cordova

I've compiled my HTML5 app using phonegap and using Boostrap 3 to help speed development.

I've installed the app on my mobile but some of my images aren't showing.

I'm using svg's but I don't think that is the problem because one of them is loading and the other two aren't. The images test fine and show fine in my web browsers but just not as an app.

Any ideas help, does this have something to do with the config.xml file and outlining the app to have access to resources from a web server?

I'm also looking for advice to how intergrating facebook login works?

Comment: Can you show what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please verify in your config.xml

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

i think issue may come ios only.

then using cordova only  not possible to achieve facebook login. so you need to integrate with facebook [connect](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin) plugin.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a go and let you know

Answer (score 0):

http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Have a look at the above link. svg has problems with android 2.3 and down.

Comment: I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S4 so I don't see this being the reason, I will include PNG fallbacks or I might try and do it via javascript with on error, but I think it might be to do with my config.xml

Comment: Brilliant the SVG doesn't want to load, png's work fine.